# Google Chrome Extension Notification API Permission Level

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Through the Chrome Extension Notification API it is possible query a permission level which informs the extension whether the user has granted or denied the extension the ability to create notifications. This is on top of the extension having the permission to access the API in the first place, which it can request and remove as it wishes. However, I can not find any way to re-grant permission to the extension to show notifications. Revoking the extensions ability to create new notifications is as easy as right-clicking a notification and selecting the option to disallow new notifications. I can't find any api-level request, or switch hidden anywhere, that lets the extension or user to re-elevate an extension's permission level back to "granted" after you have denied it. It is possible to view and change notification blocks for web pages, but browser extensions don't *appear* to have a settings page where you can view and edit this.

Does anyone know if there is a way to grant an extension the permission to create new notifications after it has been denied? Is there a page I can include directions to so a user can do this manually?

Comment: https://crbug.com/825497

Comment: Was hoping it wasn't that.